# Get root index for QTreeView and go back up one level

Tags: c++, qt

I use `QTreeView` and `QFileSystemModel` to make a very simple file explorer. Now the `QTreeView` can get confusing with it's cascading structure:

[image: image description]

This is added an option to set selected directory as root location temporary:

[image: image description]

In in the code, this is the method that will set root node to `QTreeView` by given path. At this moment I don't know how to check on invalid paths:

```
void FileView::setRootPath( const QString&str )
{
    // This didn't work
    //model->setRootPath(str);
    //This works
    ui.treeView->setRootIndex(model->index(str));
}
```

But I also want to be able to revert this oparation and go back up the directory tree. What I think I need is to get some code under following comment line:

```
void FileView::rootUpOneLevel() {
    QString rootPath;
    // Get the current root index path into the QString
     ...
    // Set the path as new root index, provided it's not out of the original root
    setRootPath(rootPath);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, if you want to reset your view and show the whole directory tree you need to simply make:

```
ui.treeView->setRootIndex(QModelIndex());
```

i.e. by providing an invalid model index, which is the root model index.

**UPDATE**

In order to go one level up you will need to call the same `setRootIndex()` function, but with the parent model index as an argument:

```
void FileView::up(const QString &str)
{
    QModelIndex idx = model->index(str);
    ui.treeView->setRootIndex(idx.parent());
}
```

or

```
// Goes one level up from the current
void FileView::up()
{
    QModelIndex currentRoot = ui.treeView->rootIndex();
    ui.treeView->setRootIndex(currentRoot.parent());
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, this works great. Now how much harder can it be to go up just one level? Therefore to actually fulfill the request of getting current *displayed* root level and perform simple `/..` operation on it?

Comment: This still doesn't really do *relative* up - you first need to check current path and pass it to `up`. It may be useful to someone else though.

Comment: `model` is an instance of QFileSystemModel which has no method `rootIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

So first I thought I can do it using paths, which worked - except on windows, it wouldn't let you list drives again. This is because there is no parent directory of `D:\`. But otherwise, this works:

```
void FileView::parentDirectory() {
    QString path = model->fileInfo(ui.treeView->rootIndex()).absoluteDir().absolutePath();
    setRootPath(path);
}
```

But there's a much better solution that uses indexes directly, avoiding some string manipulations:

```
void FileView::rootUpOneLevel() {
    ui.treeView->setRootIndex(ui.treeView->rootIndex().parent());
}
```

This will not do anything if `rootIndex().parent()` is invalid - `setRootIndex` already has the check for invalid implemented. This is the right solution.

Also although the validity is checked for you and you can call and apply `.parent()` as many times as you want without actual errors, this is the correct way to check whether more parent directories exist:

```
void FileView::rootUpOneLevel() {
    //First go up
    ui.treeView->setRootIndex(ui.treeView->rootIndex().parent());
    //Now if root node isn't valid that means there's no actual root node we could see and display
    emit parentAvailable(ui.treeView->rootIndex().isValid());
}
```